# Integral of polynomial exponential function $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}e^{c x^b } dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $a,c >0$ and $b\in(0,1)$, then $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}e^{c x^b } dx ~?$$

My try:

I tried using integration by parts, but ending up with $e^{c x^b } $ again to be integrated again and again. Any other suggestions to get a closed-form expression for this integral? If not viable, then are there any simple upper bounds for this integral?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28c*x%5Eb-ax%29+dx) doesn't find an result in terms of standard mathematical functions

Comment: You can integrate $e^{cx^b}$: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(c*x%5Eb)+dx)

Comment: It's a ${_1 \hspace {-1.5px} \Psi_0}$ [Fox-Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Expansion of $\exp$ function shows 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}e^{c x^b } dx =\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{c^n x^{nb}}{n!} dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{c^n\Gamma(1+nb)}{a^{1+nb}n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\infty e^{cx^b}e^{-ax}\ \mathrm{dx}$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c^kx^{bk}}{k!}e^{-ax}\ \mathrm{dx}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c^k}{k!}\int_0^\infty x^{bk}e^{-ax}\ \mathrm{dx}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c^k\Gamma(bk+1)}{k!a^{bk+1}}$$
$$=\frac1a\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(bk+1)}{k!}\left(\frac{c}{a^b}\right)^k$$
$$=\frac1a\ _1\hspace{-2px}\Psi_0\left[\begin{array}{c|}(1, b)\\-- \end{array}\ \frac{c}{a^{b}}\right]$$
Where $\Psi$ is the [Fox-Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function?wprov=sfla1).