# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-x^{n_1}}\sin(\alpha x^{n_2})\cos(\beta x^{n_3})\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I was doing a similar looking integral and wanted to ask what will be the general way doing it. I don’t know how to go about doing it, can anyone please help?
$$f_{n_1n_2n_3}(\alpha, \beta)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-x^{n_1}}\sin(\alpha x^{n_2})\cos(\beta x^{n_3})\,dx$$
$n_1, n_2, n_3, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$

I tried to use the complex number definition of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ but then got stuck with the following:
$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{i\alpha x^{n_2}+i\beta x^{n_3}-x^{n_1}}\,dx+\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{i\alpha x^{n_2}-i\beta x^{n_3}-x^{n_1}}\,dx-\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-i\alpha x^{n_2}+i\beta x^{n_3}-x^{n_1}}\,dx-\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-i\alpha x^{n_2}-i\beta x^{n_3}-x^{n_1}}\,dx\right]$$

Comment: Are $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ integers?

Comment: Likely no chance: Mathematica fails even with $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^3}\cos(2x^3)\sin(3x^2)\,dx$$.

Comment: @user64494 I gave that input to wolfram alpha and it gave me the output 0.320266, I don’t know but I think that with some luck it would be solvable using generalised fresnel integrals

Comment: I agree with @user64494 ... there is no reason to think $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^3}\cos(2x^3)\sin(3x^2)\,dx$$ has a closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present question generalizes [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705942/418542) to trigonometric functions of an arbitrary monomial argument. There may be no general closed-form expression. If the exponents $n_k$ are non-negative, then the integrand isn't singular. Some particular cases involving polynomial exponentials and trigonometric functions can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral). If $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$ belong to $\lbrace 0,1,2\rbrace$, then some other converging integrals may be expressed analytically. Indeed, if the integrand is invariant under $x \mapsto -x$ (i.e., $n_1$, $n_2$ are even integers), then we may rewrite the integral as
$$
f_{n_1n_2n_3}(\alpha, \beta) = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^{n_1})\sin(\alpha x^{n_2})\cos(\beta x^{n_3}) \, \text d x \, .
$$
Using the trigonometric identity
$$
\sin(\alpha x^{n_2})\cos(\beta x^{n_3}) = \tfrac12 \big(\sin(\alpha x^{n_2}-\beta x^{n_3}) + \sin(\alpha x^{n_2}+\beta x^{n_3})\big)
$$
along with Euler's formula,
the previous integral is rewritten as a linear combination of integrals of the form
$$
I_{a,b} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\!\big({-x}^{n_1} + \text i\alpha(-1)^a x^{n_2} + \text i \beta(-1)^b x^{n_3}\big) \, \text d x
$$
where $a$, $b$ belong to $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. Generalized [Gaussian integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory) from quantum field theory provide analytic expressions for particular values of $n_1$, $n_2$ in $\lbrace 0,2\rbrace$ and $n_3$ in  $\lbrace 0,1,2\rbrace$.